# javascript not hiding element when opening webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of element */
    jQuery('.logoscrollbg').each( function(i){

        var logo = jQuery(this).outerHeight();
        var position = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        /* fade out */
        if( position > logo  ){

            jQuery(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},100);

        }else{ jQuery(this).animate({'opacity':'0'},100);}

    }); 

});
```

Above is my script for a class (the header) with should blend in when the page is being scrolled down and blend out when you are on the top of the page, with other words the start.

I don't understand javascript at all, but I do a little `php` and I was wondering if someone could help me write there a `elseif` tag and later make the `els`e tag so that is the page is loaded the class(.logoscrollbg) isn't visible and when u start scrolling it gets visible and when you get to the top it gets invisivle again :)

The script works like this right now: when I enter the site it shows the bar(bad), later when scrolling it stays or well is there(good), then when getting to top again it fades out(good).

Comment: Show us the HTML code

Comment: I'm on it right now, it got quite some php which i have to convert fast ;) @PhiterFernandes

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r2t0j9bp/ here you go! :) @PhiterFernandes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inside your scroll event needs to be run when the page is loaded as well as when it scrolls.

```js
jQuery(function() {

    // object to hold our method
    var scrollCheck = {};

    // define and call our method at once
    (scrollCheck.check = function() {
  
      // only need to get scrollTop once
      var logo, position = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
  
      /* Check the location of element */
      jQuery('.logoscrollbg').each(function() {

        logo = jQuery(this).outerHeight();

        /* fade out or in */
        // cleaned this up a bit
        jQuery(this).animate({'opacity': position > logo ? 1 : 0}, 100);

      });
    })();

    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

        // call our method
        scrollCheck.check();
    });
});
```

Comment: still the same effect :/ it show the class when loading the page the first time :/

Comment: Is your javascript beneath the body or wrapped for onLoad?

Comment: Wrapped this in a document ready in case javascript used in <head>

Comment: I used the code in the body // jsfiddle.net/r2t0j9bp @TyKroll

Comment: I copyed the script in the head section and now it all works! Thanks !! :D

Comment: What the heck @TyKroll , you just copied my answer in your edit.

Comment: I wrapped my answer in document ready code when I realized OP was using js in the head rather than after the body.

Comment: What's funny is he didn't say it was in the head, he said it was in the body. "I used the code in the body..." You just updated your code after my answer went up.

Comment: I made that edit four minutes before he answered with that. Funnier is that I wrote it because I thought he was using it in the head, which turns out he wasn't. Anyhow, I didn't copy your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like this will only fire when you scroll. Try updating your js to this:

```
jQuery(window).on('scroll, load', function() {
    /* Check the location of element */
    jQuery('.logoscrollbg').each( function(i){

        var logo = jQuery(this).outerHeight();
        var position = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        /* fade out */
        if( position > logo  ){

            jQuery(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},100);

        }else{ jQuery(this).animate({'opacity':'0'},100);}

    }); 
});
```

*note: You may want to fire the callback on document load instead of window.